# HTML Inline CSS Table Row Height? (Image Out of Sync)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a HTML table but am having an issue with row heights.

I only have access to inline CSS and this is what I've got so far:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nominal TEU tdw</th>
            <th>LOA m</th>
            <th>Breath m</th>
            <th>Depth m</th>
            <th>Draft m</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                  <strong>OOCL HONG KONG</strong>
                  <strong>6 units in series</strong>
                  <strong>from May 2017</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><img class="" src="<website>/OOCL-HONG-KONG.png" alt="OOCL HONG KONG" /></td>
            <td>
                <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>21,413 teu</strong></p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">191,317 tdw</p>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>399.9</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>58.8</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>32.5</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>16.0</strong></td>
        </tr>
```

[image: Here is an image of the issue. The top is how it currently is, the bottom is what I'm struggling to achieve]

Has anyone come across this before and know a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: So you want the images to be at the bottom? Try `vertical-align:bottom;`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: `valign="bottom"` same as @Huelfe said,`vertical-align:bottom` he answered while i was trying to create the snippet

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>Nominal TEU
tdw</th>
<th>LOA
m</th>
<th>Breath
m</th>
<th>Depth
m</th>
<th>Draft
m</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><strong>OOCL HONG KONG</strong></td><td style="text-align: center;"><img class="" src="<website>/OOCL-HONG-KONG.png" alt="OOCL HONG KONG" /></td><td style="text-align: center;"  valign="bottom"><strong>21,413 teu
</strong>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<strong>6 units in series</strong><strong>from May 2017</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;">191,317 tdw</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>399.9</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>58.8</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>32.5</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>16.0</strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
```